# SQL bindparam to like query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have the following code that is not returning any results. When I change `:search_term` to just `$search_term` it will return one result as expected but when I use a wildcard it just returns 0.

```
$query = $db->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `coils` WHERE coil_name IS LIKE '%:search_term%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$perPage}");
$query->execute(array(
    ':search_term' => $search_term
));

echo $query->rowCount()
```

I have a feeling that I'm just not using it correctly. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use quotes and build a string in the query, instead, you need to do that when you bind the value (without any quotes...):

```
SELECT * FROM `coils` WHERE coil_name LIKE :search_term ORDER BY ...
```

And then later on:

```
$query->execute(array(
    ':search_term' => '%' . $search_term . '%'
));
```

Also note that you should probably use `LIKE` and not `IS LIKE`.